# Adding back in characters replaced after .replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I am currently working on a program that reverses a sentence's order, but if the sentence has punctuation, it needs to appear at the end of the new sentence.

For example: "Hi my name is Bob." Should become "Bob is name my Hi."

I have written the code necessary to reverse the String and remove all non-word characters. However, I need to know: how do I add the character that was removed to the end of the new String.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer; // for splitting


public class MyTokenTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentinel = ""; // condition for do...while
        String backward = ""; // empty string 



        do
        {

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = enter.nextLine();
        String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // array words gets tokens

        for (int count = words.length -1; count>=0; count--) // reverse the order and assign backward each token
        {
            backward += words[count].replaceAll("\\W", "") + " ";

        }

        System.out.println(backward); // print original sentence in reverse order

        System.out.println("Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: ");
            sentinel = enter.nextLine();
                sentinel = sentinel.toLowerCase(); // regardless of case




        } while (!sentinel.equals("quit")); // while the sentinel value does not equal quit, continue loop

        System.out.println("Programmed by ----");



    } // end main



} // end class MyTokenTester
```

Comment: Split the String by `String.split(" ")`. Create a `StringJoiner` with parameters `new StringJoiner(" ", "", "")`. Then iterate over the array reversed. On each one, call `StringBuilder.add(array[x])`. Print using `StringJoiner.toString()`.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the punctuation requirement. Would have to run through with a Pattern and a matcher to move everything to where it needs to go.

Comment: No problem. I"m totally unfamiliar with matching and patterns at this point in my coding experience. Would it be possible to add the last element of the array to System.out.println(backward), if so, how do I write the code for the last element in the array?

Comment: So I'm having another issue with my output, in addition to not understanding how to fix the original problem. In my output, the first sentence is repeating after each loop iteration:                                Please enter a sentence: 
Stephen is my name!
name! my is Stephen 
Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: 
1
Please enter a sentence: 
Blah
name! my is Stephen Blah 
Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: 
1
Please enter a sentence: 
blah
name! my is Stephen Blah blah 
Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: